# простая задачка,но что-то с рекурсией

Tags: javascript

ЗАДАЧА:реализуйте и экспортируйте по умолчанию функцию, которая работает следующим образом:

Дано неотрицательное целое число num. Складывать все входящие в него цифры до тех пор, пока не останется одна цифра.

Для числа 38 процесс будет выглядеть так:

3 + 8 = 11

1 + 1 = 2

Результат: 2

Примеры

```
addDigits(19); // 1
addDigits(38); // 2
addDigits(1259); // 8
```

Написал рекурсивную функцию,которая считает сумму, и если она двухзначная,то сумма передается в саму функцию. Вроде бы понятен каждый шаг, и все очевидно, но на некоторые числа он начинает выдавать "undefined". Вот говнокод:

```
var func = (numb) => {
    var str_my = String(numb);
    var summ = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < str_my.length; i++){
        summ += Number(str_my[i]);
    }
    summ >= 10 ? func(summ) : return summ;
};
```

Буду рад любой помощи. Спасибо

Comment: Для начала, вы перезаписываете сумму `var summ = 0;` в рекурсии - в чём смысл?

Comment: На всякий случай -  вся работа может быть выполнена так: ` return numb? numb%9 : 0;`

Comment: Приведенный код никак не работает из-за синтаксической ошибки: _Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'return'_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`return` надо ставить в двух местах. У вас происходила ошибка, потому что вы просто вызывали рекурсивную функцию, а не возвращали результат её работы.

Как работает код без второго return(там где вызов самой себя):

```js
func(38);

function func(str) {
    str_my = '38'
    summ = 0
    summ = 11
    if (summ >= 10) { // summ  больше или равняется 10, правда
        // выполняется этот блок кода
        func(summ); // вызвалась эта функция
    } else {
        return summ;
    }
    // функция ничего не вернула, return не сработал ни один, соответственно результат работы этой функции равен undefined
}
```

Мой вариант без тернарного оператора:

```js
function recursiveFunc(str) {
  str = String(str);
  
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    sum += +str[i];
  }
  if (sum >= 10) {
    return recursiveFunc(sum);
  } else {
    return sum;
  }
}
```

Или ваш код:

```js
var func = (numb) => {
    var str_my = String(numb);
    var summ = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < str_my.length; i++){
        summ += Number(str_my[i]);
    }
    return summ >= 10 ? func(summ) : summ;
};
```

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста,зачем нужен второй return? разве нам не достаточно одного,который возвращает уже конечную сумму?

Comment: @ЕвгенийНазарук допустим, если не поставить return, то в этой функции просто вызовет себя и всё. Т.е., эта функция ничего не вернула, а когда функция ничего не вернёт, то получится undefined

Comment: Все равно не до конца понимаю. У нас же образуется стек вызовов, и в одном из них,рано или поздно, когда число будет меньше 10, будет возврат суммы. Другим же копиям функции не нужно ничего возвращать, так как у нас по сути внутреннее состояние функции не должно изменяться или основываться на предыдущих экземплярах функций. Поправьте меня пожалуйста,где мой ход мыслей неверный. Спасибо

Comment: @ЕвгенийНазарук обновил ответ

Comment: Но ведь в той части кода,где сумма станет равна 11, вызовется снова функция, результат которой будет равен 2. 2 < 10 => возвращаем 2. Она и вернется в ответ после undefined, и "перезапишет" его?

Comment: @ЕвгенийНазарук без разницы что сделает функция, да, она что-то вернёт, но самый первый вызов функции ничего не возвращает, нету return, вы можете вызвать миллион разных функций, но функция вернёт результат только если будет так: ```return funcName(arguments);```

Comment: Понял,благодарю за объяснения